# My project stops debugging after update xamarin.forms to latest version

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

After updating Xamarin.Forms to v3.6.0.344457 my project stops debugging on Android. It deploys successfully but stops debugging immediately. Also, I installed Visual Studio 2019 and maybe it's a side effect of that.

I clean and build my project several times, factory reset my android emulator, tried to debug on VS 2017 and 2019, and the problem not solved.

> I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019 and now I can debug the project on
>   Visual Studio 2017, Maybe having VS 2017 and 2019 side by side causes
>   this problem or maybe it is a bug of VS 2019

Comment: Tools > Extensions and Updates > Mono Debugging for Visual Studio and click the Enable button.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251670/re-enabling-mono-debugger-for-xamarin.html

Comment: I have not "Mono Debugging for Visual Studio" in my installed extensions and I must say this problem occurs on a specific project and I can debug a new project without problem

Comment: could you show some error messages?